# Does halacha specify all that non-Jews should or should not do?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, noachide-laws

I see many questions here about what non-Jews in general, and Noahides in particular, may or may not do according to halacha.  Does halacha have an answer to every question about what non-Jews should or should not do?  For example, one Noahide law is "Establish courts of justice".  This means there has to be *some* means of dispensing justice in a sane society, whether or not Judaism agrees with the laws being enforced.

Comment: Does it specify all actions for Jews?

Comment: This question makes me wonder about mitzvot bein adam lchaveiro and non Jews.. Does Halacha make any of those incumbent on non Jews?

Comment: Also would the ideal courts of justice for non Jews use Jewish principles on stuff like damages?

Comment: @DoubleAA -- If you dig deep enough it comes awfully close! :-)

Comment: The Seven Laws of Noah are more "categories" than "laws".  For example, establishing courts of justice requires having standards on what constitutes "a fair trial", a prohibition on bribing judges or jurors, rules of evidence and testimony, and a prohibition of vigilante justice.